# Is there any way to optimize a triple loop in Python by using numpy or other ressources?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having trouble finding out a way to optimize a triple loop in Python. I will directly give the code for a better and simpler representation of what I have to compute :

Given two 2-D arrays named *samples* (M x N) and *D*(N x N) along with the output results (NxN):

```
for sigma in range(M):
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                results[i, j]  += (1/N) * (samples[sigma, i]*samples[sigma, j] 
                                             - samples[sigma, i]*D[j, i] 
                                             - samples[sigma, j]*D[i, j])  
return results
```

It does the job but is not effective at all in python. I tried to unloop the for i.. for j.. loop but I cannot compute it correctly with the sigma in the way.

Does someone have an idea on how to optimize those few lines ? Any suggestions are welcomed such as numpy, numexpr, etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239659/discussion-between-munshine-and-tomerikoo).

Comment: What do you mean by optimize, and by "not effective in Python"? Are you just looking for a general code review or do you have a specific, objective problem that needs to be solved?

Answer (score 2):

One way I found to improve your code (i.e reduce the number of loops) is by using `np.meshgrid`.

Here is the impovement I found. It took some fiddling but it gives the same output as your triple loop code. I kept the same code structure so you can see what parts correspond to what part. I hope this is of use to you!

```
for sigma in range(M):
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(samples[sigma], samples[sigma])

    results += (1/N) * (xx * yy 
                         - yy * D.T
                         - xx * D)       

print(results) # or return results
```

.

Edit: Here's a small script to verify that the results are as expected:

```
import numpy as np
M, N = 3, 4
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=42)


samples = rng.random((M, N))
D       = rng.random((N, N))
results = rng.random((N, N))

results_old = results.copy()
results_new = results.copy()

for sigma in range(M):
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                results_old[i, j]  += (1/N) * (samples[sigma, i]*samples[sigma, j]
                                             - samples[sigma, i]*D[j, i]
                                             - samples[sigma, j]*D[i, j])

print('\n\nresults_old', results_old, sep='\n')

for sigma in range(M):
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(samples[sigma], samples[sigma])

    results_new += (1/N) * (xx * yy
                         - yy * D.T
                         - xx * D)

print('\n\nresults_new', results_new, sep='\n')
```

**Edit 2**: Entirely getting rid of loops: it  is a bit convoluted but it essentially does the same thing.

```
M, N = samples.shape
xxx, yyy = np.meshgrid(samples, samples)
split_x = np.array(np.hsplit(np.vsplit(xxx, M)[0], M))
split_y = np.array(np.vsplit(np.hsplit(yyy, M)[0], M))

results += np.sum(
    (1/N) * (split_x*split_y 
                 - split_y*D.T 
                 - split_x*D), axis=0)

print(results) # or return results
```

Comment: When I was researching for answers, I did not encounter numpy.meshgrid at all. I still have to check the running time and compare the solutions that I got, but the code you proposed is for me a very clear and simple way of doing. I really appreciate the script for the verification and second solution (also need to see running time). Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

In order to vectorize `for` loops, we can make use of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and then reducing along any axes that are not reflected by the output array. To do so, we can "assign" one axis to each of the `for` loop indices (as a convention). For your example this means that all input arrays can be reshaped to have dimension 3 (i.e. `len(a.shape) == 3`); the axes correspond then to `sigma, i, j` respectively. Then we can perform all operations with the broadcasted arrays and finally reduce (sum) the result along the `sigma` axis (since only `i, j` are reflected in the result):

```py
# Ordering of axes: (sigma, i, j)
samples_i = samples[:, :, np.newaxis]
samples_j = samples[:, np.newaxis, :]
D_ij = D[np.newaxis, :, :]
D_ji = D.T[np.newaxis, :, :]
return (samples_i*samples_j - samples_i*D_ji - samples_j*D_ij).sum(axis=0) / N
```

The following is a complete example that compares the reference code (using `for` loops) with the above version; note that I've removed the `1/N` part in order to keep computations in the domain of integers and thus make the array equality test exact.

```py
import time
import numpy as np


def timeit(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        t_start = time.process_time()
        res = func(*args)
        t_total = time.process_time() - t_start
        print(f'{func.__name__}: {t_total:.3f} seconds')
        return res
    return wrapper


rng = np.random.default_rng()

M, N = 100, 200
samples = rng.integers(0, 100, size=(M, N))
D = rng.integers(0, 100, size=(N, N))


@timeit
def reference(samples, D):
    results = np.zeros(shape=(N, N))
    for sigma in range(M):
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                results[i, j] += (samples[sigma, i]*samples[sigma, j] 
                                  - samples[sigma, i]*D[j, i] 
                                  - samples[sigma, j]*D[i, j])
    return results


@timeit
def new(samples, D):
    # Ordering of axes: (sigma, i, j)
    samples_i = samples[:, :, np.newaxis]
    samples_j = samples[:, np.newaxis, :]
    D_ij = D[np.newaxis, :, :]
    D_ji = D.T[np.newaxis, :, :]
    return (samples_i*samples_j - samples_i*D_ji - samples_j*D_ij).sum(axis=0)


assert np.array_equal(reference(samples, D), new(samples, D))
```

This gives me the following benchmark results:

```
reference: 6.465 seconds
new: 0.133 seconds
```

Comment: Your code is similar to the one given by Walisson Cardo below. It goes slightly beyond which makes me understand better the use of broadcasting.  Walisson Cardo advised me to keep the sigma loop for memory issues depending on the size of the matrices. I need to verify this with large M and N to see what happens.  Maybe you might know what is the difference between keeping the sigma or removing it completely. If it is the case, I would likely read your answer. In any case, thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to keep the `sigma` loop, you could keep any of the loop variables. The intermediate arrays (after broadcasting) will have a size of `M*N*N`, that's the prize you pay with broadcasting. If that occupies too much memory then you would need to move one of the axis back to a `for` loop (leaving you with `N*N` (loop `sigma`), `M*N` (loop `i`) or `M*N` (loop `j`) elements per intermediate array). Since most of the iteration should take place in Numpy, you could choose the axis such as to minimize iteration in Python (i.e. `min(M, N)`).

Answer (score 1):

I found easier to break the problem into smaller steps and work on it, until we have a single equation.

Going from your original formulation:

```
for sigma in range(M):
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                results[i, j]  += (1/N) * (samples[sigma, i]*samples[sigma, j] 
                                             - samples[sigma, i]*D[j, i] 
                                             - samples[sigma, j]*D[i, j])
```

The first thing is to eliminate the `j` index in the inner most loop. For this we start working with vectors instead of single elements:

```
for sigma in range(M):
    for i in range(N):
        results[i, :]  += (1/N) * (samples[sigma, i]*samples[sigma, :] - samples[sigma, i]*D[:, i] - samples[sigma, :]*D[i, :])
```

Then, we eliminate the second loop, the one with `i` index. In this step we start to think in matrices. Therefore, each loop is the direct summation of "sigma matrices".

```
for sigma in range(M):
    results += (1/N) * (samples[sigma, :, np.newaxis] * samples[sigma] - samples[sigma, :, np.newaxis] * D.T - samples[sigma, :] * D)
```

I strongly recommend to use this step as the solution since vectorizing even more would require too much memory for a big value of `M`. But, just for knowlegde...

think of the matrices as 3-dimensional objects. We do the calculations and sum at the end in index zero as:

```
results = (1/N) * (samples[:, :, np.newaxis] * samples[:,np.newaxis] - samples[:, :, np.newaxis] * D.T - samples[:, np.newaxis, :] * D).sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: So that is how you unroll a nested loop. I tried to proceed like this when I was trying to optimize it but couldn't understand the indexes. I still have to check if everything works accordingly and get the running time for your solution. Since I'm not comfortable with the indexes yet, your code seem more complex to understand at first glance than the proposition of Andre. I am definitively keeping the process in my mind for next programs. Thank you very much for your answer !

Comment: I agree. Andre's solution surprised me, it is quite clever. It is also more readable.
Vectorization is the kind of thing you get by practicing it.

Well, about efficiency, I made some personal tests and the solutions have similar execution times.  But, as I mentioned in the solution, I would not eliminate the sigma loop. For a large input doing so would consume all of your RAM, since multiple matrices are kept in place during calculation. I think the same applies to Andre's second edit.